# Local Notification on weekdays and weekends in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to show local notification differently on weekdays and weekends in android on selecting time from time picker. I got time from picker but needs help in implementing local notification.

I had already implemented showing local notification daily at specific time using alarm manager and it is working fine but needs help to schedule on weekdays and weekends.

Answer (score 1):

To check the day of the week, you can use the `java.util.Calendar` class. First, create an instance of the calendar and get the date (in the example is the current date).

Then, retrieve the day of the week using `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`. The returned value will be an integer representing the day of the week.

```
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val date = Date()
        calendar.time = date
        val dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
        val isWeekend = dayOfWeek == Calendar.SATURDAY || dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY
```

Comment: Ok that will help to get the day of week but my question is how to schedule notification. Suppose I am scheduling notification for weekend today i.e on weekday so that will show notification on weekend at given time.